# How to check work log for individuals in Jira

Tags: logging, jira

I want to see how many total hours I have logged in Jira. Currently Jira shows a work log for individual story / sub tasks.
But is it possible to show the total amount of work logged in Jira by individual developer?

It would be nice if it shows a kind of metrics where work logged against each day is shown.

**Edit** : can I see burndown chart for individual developer?

Comment: You can also search the marketplace for free addons.
There are some good ones. For example this one (free up to version 3.4.4)
https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/org.everit.jira.timetracker.plugin/versions

Answer (score 64, accepted):

We are using the [Timesheet Reports and Gadgets Add-On for JIRA](http://www.jiratimesheet.com/#/wiki/Overview). It's available on the [Atlassian Marketplace](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/jira-timesheet-plugin) under a BSD licence, but it's [not free](http://www.jiratimesheet.com/#/wiki/Commercial).

On our JIRA 5.0.x server, it was accessible from the **Projects** tab > **Summary** page > **Reports** drop-down list > **Time Sheet Report** item.

After upgrading to JIRA 6.x, it was accessible from **Projects** tab > **Summary** page > **Reports** section heading > **Time Sheet Report**.

One tip for the timesheet report is that you don't need to give a beginning and end date for the report: it defaults to the past week. So you can bookmark the report and come back later for a report of the last week.

Comment: Thanks to Steve for recommending the Add-On and especially for tip! I'd like to add, that since version 2.5 it is possible to subscribe to  report to receive it regularly by email, nice?

Comment: In Jira 7, I get there by going to my project, then Reports on the left, then it's the very last item on the page in my setup.

Answer (score 45):

One of the free option available is to use the browser extension named Jira Assistant available in below url. This extension has lot more useful features which not only helps to generate report, but also help to log your work on daily basis with notifications, calendar integrations and lot more cool features which helps both managers and team members in their daily activity:

[image]

Visit https://www.jiraassistant.com for more details.

For web version: https://app.jiraassistant.com/

For Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jira-assistant/momjbjbjpbcbnepbgkkiaofkgimihbii?src=atls_ans

For Firefox extension: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jira-assistant/

For Edge: https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/jira-assistant-worklog-/aoenpdbabcjnjbjpegeenodfknllmaoi?utm_source=atls_ans

Disclaimer: I am the developer of this app

Comment: Chrome extension was actually built by none other than the writer of this answer!  Downloaded and installed it, havent used it extensively but it seems pretty slick.  Includes a "Daywise" report that lets you see hows logged by you for a particular time range, giving just what the original poster requested.

Comment: @Shridhar L Thank you very much for this extension! I love it!

Comment: This extension is wonderful!  It is definitely worth trying!!!  Works well in Opera.

Comment: Thanks! This is really what I've looked for.

Answer (score 20):

If you use atlassian, select your project, then go to the left toolbar and click diagram and select this report:

[image]

Comment: How could you use Jira but not Atlassian? Anyway, I have this exact screen except "Time Tracking Report" is not on it.

Comment: Can I filter by my hours here?

Answer (score 14):

There is no build in good way to achieve it but the maximum you can take with build in functionalities is following.

**Options 1:**
Create filter like following JQL:
`worklogDate > startofWeek(-1w) AND worklogAuthor = john.smith`

Then using worklog "Pie Chart" widget to sum. It is available for standard Dashboard. In "maximized" view it gives table with the numbers. It allows breaking by certain criteria. Then for each user you will need a widget on a dashboard to track which is not convenient.

**Options 2:**
 Use filter like given above to create Agile board and leverage "TimeTrackingReport" or "WorkLog" reports. Please bear in mind that Worklog report can be narrowed by User but does not give much flexibility  [image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: "...for each user you will need a widget..." - no. In your JQL use "worklogAuthor = currentUser()" and each dashboard widget will customize itself to the logged-in user.

Answer (score 9):

## Dashboards -> My Dash -> [+ Add A Gaget] -> Tempo User Timesheet -> Add

will show total time for each day/tickets etc.

[image]

Comment: In our case the gadget was called "Time Sheet", but the process worked flawlessly.

Comment: is this still available? I'm not ale to find it

Answer (score 6):

You can use query like below in JIRA

```
project in ("TEST_PROJECT") AND worklogAuthor in ("testuser@testjira.com") AND worklogDate >= startOfMonth()
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible with plain JIRA. You could use the REST api to build something yourself, or look at the various time tracking plugins for JIRA (Like [Tempo](http://www.tempoplugin.com/)). See also https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACOM/Using+JIRA+For+Time+Tracking

Comment: Please add a comment if you down vote to know why this is not a good answer in your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "sumUp for Jira" plugin

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1211625/sumup-for-jira?hosting=cloud&tab=overview

its sums up any numeric field values incl. worklogs and displays the sums in the issue navigator, dashboard gadgets or custom fields

You can create a filter with current user assignee and create a board with it and then you can add a burndown gadget to a dashboard to see the chart for each one

Answer (score 0):

You could also query your Jira database and get that data from there and then use it in a data visualization software of your choice.

Here is an example where you can retrieve that data:

```
select i.summary, au.lower_user_name as "User Name", round(w.timeworked/3600,2) as "Hours", w.startdate as "Work Date" from worklog w left join jiraissue i on i.id=w.issueid left join cwd_user u on u.user_name = w.author left join app_user au on w.author = au.user_key left join project p on p.id = i.PROJECT where TO_CHAR(w.startdate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')= ${date} and p.id = ${PROJECT_ID} and (au.lower_user_name = ${user_key} or au.user_key = ${user_key})enter code here
```

This example has a *where* clause for a given start date, project (id) and user.